# Conversion process hangs under AWS Schema Conversion Tool

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-sct

During a recent AWS webinar, a database conversion initiated under the Schema Conversion Tool resulted in the process hanging.  I am providing a screenshot below:

[image: schema conversion tool screenshot]

If one encounters such a problem, what would be the procedure to debug this?  Is the problem happening at the source schema, which is an MS SQL Server database?  Would looking at database logs help?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue with MSSQL.  Hangs analyzing a procedure.

Comment: @developing2020 No, sorry.  Incidentally, I gave up on AWS, switched to Azure.